# How do I manually build form data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:

```
Subject has_many Points
Point belongs_to Subject
```

Points are created using a form, and the controller is as follows

```
  def create
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])    
    @point = @subject.points.build(params[:point])
    if @point.save
      flash[:success] = "You have created new data"
      redirect_to subject_path(@point.subject_id)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

At the moment a user can create Points for each Subject using a form. However, I want to also allow the user to upload mass points from a csv file. For this I am using the csv library (ruby 1.9.3)

After uploading the csv file, I put the csv file into a table as follows

```
thegrid = CSV.table(path, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol)
```

Where path is the path to the csv. The headers for the csv file match the column names in the database (including the subject_id column number)

I want to loop through the rows in the table and add each one to the database as follows

```
  <% point = Hash.new %>
  <% thegrid.each do |row| %>
    <% 
     point = {     
              "name" => row[0],
              "total_points" => row[1], 
              "subject_id" => row[2]
             }
    %>
    <% @point = @subject.points.build(params[point]) %>
  <% end %>
```

But the above doesn't appear to add the rows to the database. What is the correct way to do this loop, I think it may be the params that are causing a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted this issue by updating the code as follows:

```
<% 
 params[:point] = {     
           name: row[0],
           total_points: row[1], 
           subject_id: row[2]
         }
%>
<% @point = @subject.points.build(params[:point]) %>
```